# ReadOnlyCollection C#

Tags: c#

I  have Category model

```
public class Category : BindableBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the Category class.
    /// </summary>
    public Category()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    private int _CategoryId = -1;

    public int CategoryId
    {
        get { return _CategoryId; }
        set { _CategoryId = value; }
    }

    private string _Name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name.Trim(); }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }

    private Type _DataType;

    public Type DataType
    {
        get { return _DataType; }
        set { _DataType = value; }
    }


    }

    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

In Another main class

```
      private static ReadOnlyCollection<Category> _CategoryList;

    public static ReadOnlyCollection<Category> CategoryList
    {
        get { return _CategoryList; }
        set { _CategoryList = value; }
    }
```

I am populating the CategoryList from a datatable .

```
private static List<Category> GenerateCategoryList(DataSet ds)
    {
        List<Category> categoryList = new List<Category>();

        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["Category"].Rows)
        {
            Category category = new Category();
            category.Name = row["Name"].ToString();

            int categoryId;
            if (int.TryParse(row["Category_Id"].ToString(), out categoryId))
                category.CategoryId = categoryId;

            int MappingId;
            if (int.TryParse(row["Category_Id_0"].ToString(), out MappingId))
                category.MappingId = MappingId;

            int RootId;
            if (int.TryParse(row["Properties_Id"].ToString(), out RootId))
                category.RootId = RootId;

            categoryList.Add(category);
        }

        return categoryList;
    }
```

Once i am done with the above method i am using the CategoryList in two methods

```
var GenCatTask = await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => { await GetCatgeoryFromAdapter(); });
        await GenCatTask.ContinueWith(async t => { MainTreeNoProperty = await GenerateCategory(CategoryList, null); });===>CAll 1
        await GenCatTask.ContinueWith(async t => { MainTree = await GenerateCategory(CategoryList, PropertyList); }); ====>CALL2

private static async Task<List<Category>> GenerateCategory(ReadOnlyCollection<Category> Categories, ReadOnlyCollection<PropertyNode> Properties)
    {
        try
        {
            List<Category> TreeList = new List<Category>();
            List<Category> categories = Categories.Where(i => i.RootId == 0).ToList();
            categories.ForEach(category =>
            {
                TreeList.Add(category);
            });

            LogEntries(LogType.Info, "Retrieving Category List ", "ModuleController", 75);
            if (categories.Count > 0)
                SetCategories(TreeList, Categories, Properties);
            LogEntries(LogType.Info, "Completed Retrieving Category List ", "ModuleController", 100);
            return TreeList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogEntries(LogType.Error, "Error- While GenerateCategory", "ModuleController", 100, ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

When call the above code. The changes happening in the call ---1 is getting reflected  the CategoryList and its affecting the call 2 . How can I make the CategoryList as ready Only and I am not supposed to change the collection inside the categoryList .But the collection is getting affected .

[image: During the call 1 the Categories inside the CategoryList is Null]

[image: After the first call the Categories are getting added . I dont want this to happen]

Comment: `private set` that makes it readonly for all other classes.